# Using Json in KRL

Tags: json, krl

I'm having trouble with parsing my Json, when i place the url in the browser i get this as a return `{"token": "7xv6r32eay5n376", "secret": "589bc72ix7mowua"}` So all i want to do is get that string and parse out the token and secret and display the values in a notify to confirm i'm getting the correct information. Can anyone see what i'm doing wrong?

```
    rule first_rule {
    select when pageview ".*" setting ()
    pre{
    json=http:get(/* I place my URL here */);
    content   = json.pick("$..content");
    token=content.decode();
    tok=token.pick("$..token");
    sec=token.pick("$..secret");
    message="Token: "+tok+" "+"Secret: "+sec;
    }    
    notify("Values: ",message);    
  }
}
```

Comment: so i fixed my KRL problem, crazy one too. I guess when using http:get(); you must use double quotes "" not single '' in the get().

Comment: you can answer your own question and then people can vote it up. ; )

Comment: I guess stackoverflow will not let me answer until i have been a user for 24 hours, so i'll answer it when they allow me ;)

Comment: You could also use `dataset` or `datasource` instead of `http:get()`. Makes your code a little cleaner. :)

Comment: Yeah i was thinking about that but i didn't want this code to run every time the app runs.

Comment: datasource doesn't run each time. you could also assign your url to a variable and set it to null after the http:get in case it gets into the generated javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so i fixed my KRL problem, I guess when using http:get(); you must use double quotes "" not single '' in the get().

Comment: is there a reason why http:get shouldn't work with single quotes?

Comment: I'm not sure the reason for it, but when I tried single quotes it did not work.